# Checking if User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my site, I'd like to see if a user is logged in on every page request. So I have this in my global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // do something
    }            
}
```

But I keep getting an object reference error, the User is always null, even if I'm logged in.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **Application_AuthenticateRequest** to get the user reference where you can check if user is authenticated.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
   access now Context.User
   }     
}
```